# ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: while dockerize sails.js app with mysql

Tags: mysql, docker, sails.js

I am trying to dockerize a sails.js app which is using mysql image, but I am getting an error. I tried many solutions from stackoverflow and github but non have worked. And I dont have any experience with docker. Its my client requirement to work with it. Here is the code of my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:

  sailsjs:
    build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  ports:
   - 80:1337
  volumes:
   - .:/usr/src/app

  mysqlsails:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: pricing_engine
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
    volumes:
     - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
 mysql-data:
```

And datastores.js

```
module.exports.datastores = {
 default: {
  adapter: require('sails-mysql'),
  host: 'mysqlsails',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'pricing_engine',
  insecureAuth : true                                                                      
 },
};
```

Comment: Can you put your Dockerfile from sailsjs? @AGk

Comment: thanks @RobertoGonçalves actually there was issue in node image.so after removing node image and rebuild its working now..

Comment: Oh, great that you could solve it! A really important tip for the next time is putting everything needed for anyone to replicate your problem, ok? Because it is a little harder to do that without everything.